# Linq get parent and child in one table and calculate their values in another table

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have 2 tables:

```
ParentID | ChildID  
--------   -------  
91209      91210   
91209      91211
91212      91213
91212      91214
```

```
RecordID | Quantity 
--------   ---------
91209      1500
91210      2500
91211      7200
91212      6000
91213      5000
91214      6000
```

I would like the result to be:

```
RecordId | Total Quantity
--------   --------------
91209      11200
91212      17000
```

I have tried some complicated join queries but I don't seem to get the result I need. Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the table names acc.

```
var parentRecords = records.Select(x => 
        new Record { RecordID = parents.FirstOrDefault(y => y.ChildID == x.RecordID || y.ParentID == x.RecordID).ParentID, Quantity = x.Quantity});

    var result = parentRecords.GroupBy(z => z.RecordID,
        (key, value) => new { RecordID= key, TotalQuantity= value.Sum(a => a.Quantity) });
```

Comment: Brilliant! The Edit works like a charm. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad it helped! Please, consider accepting my answer.